# Choosing projection for mapping both North America and South America

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, north-america, south-america

I'm using ArcMap (10.7.1) to produce a map that shows most of North and South America, from approximately 14.0 to 74.0 latitude and -106 to -42 longitude.

What projection is recommended for this type of map?

I have found suggestions for North and South America separately, but not for this entire area.

I am familiar with how to re-define the central meridian, so would using a Mercator projection but redefining the central meridian to be the center of my map be the most accurate way to represent this large area?

Comment: WGS 84, aka EPSG4326.

Comment: @Erik, right now I'm using: -------

WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
WKID: 3857 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Central_Meridian: 0.0
Standard_Parallel_1: 0.0
Auxiliary_Sphere_Type: 0.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0) ------- Would this suffice?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://projectionwizard.org/ to choose an appropriate projection

Comment: Thanks @Jake, I hadn't heard of that before!